# PRISM 4 UICompositionQuickStart question

Tags: dependency-injection, prism

In this quickstart example, CreateShell() has

```
ShellView view = this.Container.TryResolve<ShellView>();
```

My question is how does the shellview got created without passing the viewmodel parameter. The constructor for Shellview is defined as

```
public ShellView(ShellViewModel viewModel)
{
    // ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the whole point of dependency injection. If the container could not instantiate objects that have dependencies themselves it wouldn't be very practical to use.

The answer is that the container reflects on `ShellView` and finds the constructor with the greatest amount of parameters (trivial here, as there is only one to choose from). Then, for each parameter, it looks up its type `ShellViewModel` and then recursively tries to find out how to instantiate the parameter.

Assuming that at some point the "tree" of dependencies ends (it finds dependencies that do not have constructor parameters, like `ShellViewModel` here), it starts constructing the dependencies and finally gets to the object you requested.

In this example, it sees that it can create a `ShellViewModel` trivially (and does so), then calls the `ShellView` constructor with that object as an argument.